# Which geo-location available in Twitter data should I use?

Tags: geometry, geolocation, twitter

I am extracting twitter location on my side.Few tweets has perfect location but in most cases additional details are available (i.e.  Country,bounding_box,poly lines etc)

So confused regarding selecting proper location.

Consider following case  in which country is given and additional information like bounding box and geometry is available.

Please check the screenshots

[image: Part 1] [image: Part 2]

**Complete Twitter string** : [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/2742w/) to see complete extracted tweet (too long hence put on JSFiddle). Due to some reason modified twitter ID's.

So which geo-location should I consider?

If I go country wise then getting many tweets on single point so I am confused.

Therefore, any help/suggestion will be great!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: it'd be better to show an image showing the problem.

Comment: I see, well I think you could use jsfiddle to post those features with openlayers, so we can check the geolocations

Comment: Reverse Geocode comes back with Accuracy https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/reverse_geocode then filter anything below 1000m.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little too late, but the way I have been handling the bounding boxes is by using (X1+X2)/2, (Y1+Y2)/2   as my XY coordinates, and plotting those directly.

That way I at least have an average coordinate set for the event. This way I am able to quickly produce coordinates without complex programming to "draw" bounding boxes since I mostly use ArcGIS (but I love me some QGIS).

CONSIDERATION:  Hypothetically, you could have the centroid of a bounding box be outside of a country...

MUSINGS:
I have also been considering assigning values to specific fields(haven't done it yet), where if I have user provided location, I would trigger a higher value than the country bounding box, or the place bounding box. This would be a more comprehensive approach to identifying the "location" of a tweet.  I have been piping the user location to GoogleMaps API(with some filtering to remove places like Hogwarts, and Nowhere).